# Batch processing of the XML file with optional values?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am parsing the xml file using the BatchProcessing process, I just want to make the field optional to read from the `StaxEventItemReader`, please check the below lines of code of it.

```
 StaxEventItemReader<DataWrapper> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<DataWrapper>();

    reader.setResource(new PathResource(filePath));

    reader.setFragmentRootElementName("MY_LIST");


    Map<String, Class<?>> aliases = new HashMap<>();
    aliases.put("MY_LIST", DataWrapper.class);

    XStreamMarshaller xStreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();

    xStreamMarshaller.setAliases(aliases);

    xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().addPermission(AnyTypePermission.ANY);


    reader.setUnmarshaller(xStreamMarshaller);


    SynchronizedItemStreamReader<DataWrapper> synchronizedItemStreamReader = new SynchronizedItemStreamReader<>();
    synchronizedItemStreamReader.setDelegate(reader);

    return synchronizedItemStreamReader;
```

How to make the field option for the my reader for the **Field 3**, please check the below XMl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Fields xmlns:xsi="http://www.wwww.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <FileCreationDate>2021-04-30T00:15:55.0725852-07:00</FileCreationDate>
  <MY_LIST>
    <Field 1>Fileld 1 data</Field 1>
    <Field 2>Fileld 2 data</Field 2>
    <Field 3>Fileld 3 data</Field 3> /// I WANT TO PUT IT AS THE OPTIONAL WHILE READING
  </MY_LIST>
</Fields>
```

I want the Field 3 optional because it comes sometime. Yet now in BatchProcessing it is mandatory to parse all field.I am following this tutor for my BatchProcessing task , please ceck it once [Click here](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-batch-tutorial-reading-information-from-an-xml-file/)

Comment: Please put some actual code instead of some dumbed down version. Fields are optional (unless there is an xsd that thinks otherwise or you have it mandatory with jaxb annotions).

Comment: What do you mean by optional? If the field does not exists the attribute in the DTO will be null

Comment: Optional means that I do not want to parse this field. Actually BatchProcessor requires all filelds to parse. Is there any property is available for it, please help me on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all suggestion , I have fixed the solution by the         `ignoreUnknownElements();` of the `XStream` class.

Since XStream 1.4.5 durring marshaller declaration it's enough to use ignoreEnknownElements() method:

```
XStreamMarshaller marshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
marshaller.getXStream().ignoreUnknownElements();
```